# Handle separator with Material dayjs date adapter

Tags: angular-material, dayjs

In my Angular application I need to swap from [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to [dayjs](https://day.js.org/).
Because I am using [material](https://material.angular.io/) I have to replace `moment-date-adapter` with a dayjs-date-adapter, so I write my own date adapter but I can't understand how momentjs can parse a date like `12122020` without any separator (you can see it in action [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jladbrqneye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts)).

I try to achieve it by setting this `MatDateFormats`, with an array of dateinput.
But I don't know if it is the best solution because I don't see it in moment-date-adapter

```
MatDateFormats = {
parse: {
    dateInput: ['D/M/YYYY', 'DMYYYY'],
},
display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
}
```

}

This is my `dayjs-date-adapter`

```
export interface DayJsDateAdapterOptions {
/**
 * Turns the use of utc dates on or off.
 * Changing this will change how Angular Material components like DatePicker output dates.
 * {@default false}
 */
useUtc?: boolean;
}

/** InjectionToken for Dayjs date adapter to configure options. */
export const MAT_DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<DayJsDateAdapterOptions>(
'MAT_DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: MAT_DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS_FACTORY
});

export function MAT_DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS_FACTORY(): DayJsDateAdapterOptions {
 return {
    useUtc: false
 };
}

/** Creates an array and fills it with values. */
function range<T>(length: number, valueFunction: (index: number) => T): T[] {
 const valuesArray = Array(length);
 for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    valuesArray[i] = valueFunction(i);
 }
 return valuesArray;
}

/** Adapts Dayjs Dates for use with Angular Material. */
export class DayjsDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<Dayjs> {
 private localeData: {
    firstDayOfWeek: number,
    longMonths: string[],
    shortMonths: string[],
    dates: string[],
    longDaysOfWeek: string[],
    shortDaysOfWeek: string[],
    narrowDaysOfWeek: string[]
 };

constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) public dateLocale: string,
            @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS) private options?: 
   DayJsDateAdapterOptions) {
    super();

    this.initializeParser(dateLocale);
  }

private get shouldUseUtc(): boolean {
    const {useUtc}: DayJsDateAdapterOptions = this.options || {};
    return !!useUtc;
}

// TODO: Implement
setLocale(locale: string) {
    super.setLocale(locale);

    const dayJsLocaleData = this.dayJs().localeData();
    this.localeData = {
        firstDayOfWeek: dayJsLocaleData.firstDayOfWeek(),
        longMonths: dayJsLocaleData.months(),
        shortMonths: dayJsLocaleData.monthsShort(),
        dates: range(31, (i) => this.createDate(2017, 0, i + 1).format('D')),
        longDaysOfWeek: range(7, (i) => this.dayJs().set('day', i).format('dddd')),
        shortDaysOfWeek: dayJsLocaleData.weekdaysShort(),
        narrowDaysOfWeek: dayJsLocaleData.weekdaysMin(),
    };
}

getYear(date: Dayjs): number {
    return this.dayJs(date).year();
}

getMonth(date: Dayjs): number {
    return this.dayJs(date).month();
}

getDate(date: Dayjs): number {
    return this.dayJs(date).date();
}

getDayOfWeek(date: Dayjs): number {
    return this.dayJs(date).day();
}

getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    return style === 'long' ? this.localeData.longMonths : this.localeData.shortMonths;
}

getDateNames(): string[] {
    return this.localeData.dates;
}

getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    if (style === 'long') {
        return this.localeData.longDaysOfWeek;
    }
    if (style === 'short') {
        return this.localeData.shortDaysOfWeek;
    }
    return this.localeData.narrowDaysOfWeek;
}

getYearName(date: Dayjs): string {
    return this.dayJs(date).format('YYYY');
}

getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return this.localeData.firstDayOfWeek;
}

getNumDaysInMonth(date: Dayjs): number {
    return this.dayJs(date).daysInMonth();
}

clone(date: Dayjs): Dayjs {
    return date.clone();
}

createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): Dayjs {
    const returnDayjs = this.dayJs()
        .set('year', year)
        .set('month', month)
        .set('date', date);
    return returnDayjs;
}

today(): Dayjs {
    return this.dayJs();
}

parse(value: any, parseFormat: string): Dayjs | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
        return this.dayJs(value, parseFormat, this.locale);
    }
    return value ? this.dayJs(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
}

format(date: Dayjs, displayFormat: string): string {
    if (!this.isValid(date)) {
        throw Error('DayjsDateAdapter: Cannot format invalid date.');
    }
    return date.locale(this.locale).format(displayFormat);
}

addCalendarYears(date: Dayjs, years: number): Dayjs {
    return date.add(years, 'year');
}

addCalendarMonths(date: Dayjs, months: number): Dayjs {
    return date.add(months, 'month');
}

addCalendarDays(date: Dayjs, days: number): Dayjs {
    return date.add(days, 'day');
}

toIso8601(date: Dayjs): string {
    return date.toISOString();
}


deserialize(value: any): Dayjs | null {
    let date;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
        date = this.dayJs(value);
    } else if (this.isDateInstance(value)) {
        // NOTE: assumes that cloning also sets the correct locale.
        return this.clone(value);
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        if (!value) {
            return null;
        }
        date = this.dayJs(value).toISOString();
    }
    if (date && this.isValid(date)) {
        return this.dayJs(date);
    }
    return super.deserialize(value);
}

isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    return dayjs.isDayjs(obj);
}

isValid(date: Dayjs): boolean {
    return this.dayJs(date).isValid();
}

invalid(): Dayjs {
    return this.dayJs(null);
}

private dayJs(input?: any, format?: string, locale?: string): Dayjs {
    if (!this.shouldUseUtc) {
        return dayjs(input, format, locale, false);
    }
    return dayjs(input, {format, locale, utc: this.shouldUseUtc}, locale, false).utc();
}

private initializeParser(dateLocale: string) {
    if (this.shouldUseUtc) {
        dayjs.extend(utc);
    }

    dayjs.extend(LocalizedFormat);
    dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);
    dayjs.extend(localeData);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dateInput that you use in the parse property of MatDateFormats is used in the parse function of your dayjs-date-adapter. Right now you supply an array as dateInput, but your function expects a string. Dayjs (unlike moment) cannot handle an array of formats. If you want to use an array, to support multiple formats, you must figure out which format of the array to use in your parse function. The easiest way to do this is probably just to loop over your possible formats and return the dayjs object if it is valid.

Something like this (note I have not tested this):

```
parse(value: any, parseFormats: string[]): Dayjs | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
        parseFormats.forEach(parseFormat => {
            const parsed = this.dayJs(value, parseFormat, this.locale);
            if (parsed.isValid()) {
                return parsed;
            }
        }
        // return an invalid object if it could not be parsed with the supplied formats
        return this.dayJs(null);
}
    return value ? this.dayJs(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
}
```

Note in my own adapter I altered the private dayJs function a little bit, because providing locale also in the format options gave me some weird behavior. I didn't need the utc options, so I ended up using:

```
private dayJs(input?: any, format?: string, locale?: string): Dayjs {
    return dayjs(input, format, locale);
}
```

---

An alternative to the approach above would be to just supply 1 dateInput (like : dateInput: 'D/M/YYYY'). And then make the parse function a little bit more flexible. I ended up with this:

```
parse(value: any, parseFormat: string): Dayjs | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
        const longDateFormat = dayjs().localeData().longDateFormat(parseFormat); // MM/DD/YYY or DD-MM-YYYY, etc.
        // return this.dayJs(value, longDateFormat);
        let parsed = this.dayJs(value, longDateFormat, this.locale);
        if (parsed.isValid()) {
            // string value is exactly like long date format
            return parsed;
        }
        const alphaNumericRegex = /[\W_]+/;
        if (!alphaNumericRegex.test(value)) {
            // if string contains no non-word characters and no _
            // user might have typed 24012020 or 01242020
            // strip long date format of non-word characters and take only the length of the value so we get DDMMYYYY or DDMM etc
            const format = longDateFormat.replace(/[\W_]+/g, '').substr(0, value.length);
            parsed = this.dayJs(value, format, this.locale);
            if (parsed.isValid()) {
                return parsed;
            }
        }
        const userDelimiter = alphaNumericRegex.exec(value) ? alphaNumericRegex.exec(value)![0] : '';
        const localeDelimiter = alphaNumericRegex.exec(longDateFormat) ? alphaNumericRegex.exec(longDateFormat)![0] : '';
        const parts = value.split(userDelimiter);
        const formatParts = longDateFormat.split(localeDelimiter);
        if (parts.length <= formatParts.length && parts.length < 4) {
            // right now this only works for days, months, and years, if time should be supported this should be altered
            let newFormat = '';
            parts.forEach((part, index) => {
                // get the format in the length of the part, so if a the date is supplied 1-1-19 this should result in D-M-YY
                // note, this will not work if really weird input is supplied, but that's okay
                newFormat += formatParts[index].substr(0, part.length);
                if (index < parts.length - 1) {
                    newFormat += userDelimiter;
                }
            });
            parsed = this.dayJs(value, newFormat);
            if (parsed.isValid()) {
                return parsed;
            }
        }

        // not able to parse anything sensible, return something invalid so input can be corrected
        return this.dayJs(null);
    }

    return value ? this.dayJs(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
}
```

If you only want to support number only inputs (like 28082021) beside your specified input, you need the if statement with !alphaNumericRegex.test(value). This piece of code takes out any delimiters (like - or /) from your formatting string and also makes sure string with only days or days and months are supported (28 or 2808 for example). It will use the current month and year to fill up the missing values. If you only want to support full day-month-year strings you can omit the .substr part.

The piece of code below this if statement causes different types of user input to be supported, like 28-08-2021, 28/08/2021, 28 08 2021, 28-08-21, 28/08 etc..
I'm sure it won't work for every language, but it works for the most used userinputs in my language (dutch).

Hope this helps someone who has been struggling with this as well!